# How to convert a LinearLayout to image?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-linearlayout

I tried the following code to convert the `LinearLayout` to image:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout lyt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt);
    lyt.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    lyt.buildDrawingCache(true);

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(lyt.getDrawingCache());

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageBitmap(b);

}
```

but I got `NullPointerException` in :

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(lyt.getDrawingCache());
```

where the layout XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***Try below code, it work***

**Add below permission in manifest**

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

> **MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private Button saveBtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_view);
        saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.save_btn:
            File file = saveBitMap(this, linearLayout);    //which view you want to pass that view as parameter
            if (file != null) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Drawing saved to the gallery!");
            } else {
                Log.i("TAG", "Oops! Image could not be saved.");
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    private File saveBitMap(Context context, View drawView){
        File pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"Handcare");
        if (!pictureFileDir.exists()) {
            boolean isDirectoryCreated = pictureFileDir.mkdirs();
            if(!isDirectoryCreated)
                Log.i("ATG", "Can't create directory to save the image");
            return null;
        }
        String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() +File.separator+ System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
        File pictureFile = new File(filename);
        Bitmap bitmap =getBitmapFromView(drawView);
        try {
            pictureFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oStream);
            oStream.flush();
            oStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("TAG", "There was an issue saving the image.");
        }       
            scanGallery( context,pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
        return pictureFile;
    }
    //create bitmap from view and returns it
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        //Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null) {
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        }   else{
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
    // used for scanning gallery
    private void scanGallery(Context cntx, String path) {
        try {
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(cntx, new String[] { path },null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks :) your answer shows me an important hint to set background, which works like charm.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are executing that code in onCreate. The problem with that is that the views are not layouted yet. Either call lyt.measure or call the code later. e.g: to onSizeChanged() or in onLayout() after you called super.onLayout().

Comment: how to call lyt.onMeasure() ??!

Comment: sorry the function is measure(). But i recommend to create the bitmap later and not call measure().

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(lyt.getDrawingCache());
```

the only thing that can be `null` in that line is `lyt`, the rest can't. You probably did not set the layout yet and `findViewById()` will return `null` in that case.

You have to do `setContentView()` before you can do `findViewById()`

Comment: Hmm that should mean the error does not happen on that line but somewhere inside `Bitmap.createBitmap()` or `lyt.getDrawingCache()`. And I guess Renard is right, if the views did not layout themselves they don't know how to draw themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code snipet which converts xml layouts to Bitmap images

```
private Bitmap convertLayoutToImage() {
        LinearLayout linearView = (LinearLayout) this.getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout
                .marker_layout, null, false); //you can pass your xml layout

        linearView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        linearView.layout(0, 0, linearView.getMeasuredWidth(), linearView.getMeasuredHeight());

        linearView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        linearView.buildDrawingCache();
        return linearView.getDrawingCache();// creates bitmap and returns the same
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See if that helps you:

[Converting Views to Bitmap Images in Android](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/30676.aspx)