# Bitmap from ImageView after onTouch

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have an imageview, and after i add image (a marker) on this imageview.
At the end, i want to create a bitmap, included the new marker.
But if i try to create a bitmap from relative layout, i create an image without new marker! Why?

```
    imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    //insert a marker on my imageview
    final RelativeLayout rr = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
    rr.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
              int x = (int) event.getX() ;
              int y = (int) event.getY();
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);; //Assuming you use a RelativeLayout
              ImageView iv=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
              lp.setMargins(x,y,0,0);
              iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
              iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker));
              ((ViewGroup)v).addView(iv);

    //create a bitmap from relative layout but the new bitmap is without marker
    Bitmap b1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(rr.getWidth(), rr.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b1);
    ((ViewGroup)v).draw(c);

          }
          return false;
    }
```

Comment: It happens because you are adding marker dynamically to the layout, becuase to add dynamic views it has some delay. Thats the reason creating bitmap without marker. On second touch with singe marker bitmap will be created.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how can i fix the problem?

Comment: I solved the problem! I created a variable "count" that at the second touch does not add the marker, but save bitmap! And after first touch, a toast show to touch the screen to the user for confirm.
Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Another better solution is given below. Look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It happens because adding marker dynamically to the layout, to add dynamic views it has some delay. Thats the reason creating bitmap without marker. On second touch with singe marker bitmap will be created. The solution is save bitmap after some delay.**

**Solution is here:**

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();      //handler object in global

rr.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
          int x = (int) event.getX() ;
          int y = (int) event.getY();
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);; //Assuming you use a RelativeLayout
          ImageView iv=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
          lp.setMargins(x,y,0,0);
          iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
          iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker));
          ((ViewGroup)v).addView(iv);

          //run handler after 1000 milli seconds i.e 1 sec
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
      }
      return false;
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //wrote your block of code here
        //create a bitmap from relative layout but the new bitmap is without marker
        Bitmap b1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(rr.getWidth(), rr.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b1);
       ((ViewGroup)v).draw(c);
    }
};
```

Look here [How to Save Bitmap as image in SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374547/how-to-convert-a-linearlayout-to-image/28067777#28067777)

Comment: Ok but i am a new user of stack, and i need 15 reputation for vote

Comment: No problem. I am saying just because it is useful to others